# How to Solve Redis Multiplexer in ASP.NET Core Problem

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I my dotnet core project i am using redis for caching. In work fine in local,but i am getting following error in ubuntu server

**Error**

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketClosed on PING
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(String configuration, TextWriter log) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 799
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAndRefreshAsync(String key, Boolean getData, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.RefreshAsync(String key, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Unhandled Exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketClosed on PING
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(String configuration, TextWriter log) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 799
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.SetAsync(String key, Byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
   at otpservice.Helper.HOtp.GenerateOtp(String userid) in D:\SampleHelper\HOtp.cs:line 39
   at otpservice.Controllers.OtpController.Otp(Object userData) in D:\Sample\Controllers\OtpController.cs:line 41
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
Aborted
```

**ConfigureService method in Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
  {
     options.InstanceName = "Sample";
     //For the Server i am using IP Instead of localhost
     options.Configuration = "localhost";
  });
```

**During caching in my Code**

```
 var cache = new RedisCache(new RedisCacheOptions
  {
      //For the Server i am using IP Instead of localhost
      Configuration = "localhost",
  });
```

How to Solve the error.

Thank you...

Comment: When you just give localhost, it will try to connect to redis instance with default  redis port, i.e., localhost:6379. Check if the redis is accessible on this port or the port is allow. So if you are hosting redis on different server, check that on which port redis is running and use that also in the configuration. If it's on the same server open redis client and check. You can get more information from here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04